# Meaning of Mermaid Ring?

Tags: fraternal-organization

My grandfather owned a ring that we have recently identified as a mermaid ring with his initials (WCJ) on the top in an "oriental" font that was popular in the 1920s and 1930s:

[image]
[image]

Did rings like this have any particular meaning at that time?  The fact that it's so worn means it was important to him, not sure if that's because he just liked it, or whether it had a meaning in some fraternal organization or such ...

Comment: I don't know where it's from, but it seems to have been a style at that time. Similar rings at https://www.1stdibs.com/jewelry/rings/cocktail-rings/antique-deco-mermaid-ring-signet-14-karat-gold-diamond-vintage-fine-jewelry/id-j_7278562/ and https://www.pinterest.com/pin/221872719127218699/ and https://www.etsy.com/listing/723155277/old-european-cut-diamond-vintage-signet

Comment: Are there any markings on the inside of the ring? The lower photo suggests there might be something there.

Comment: The only markings on the inside are "14K".  Good eyes!

Comment: The overall style - mythical creature, scrollwork, 'Chinese' initials and a single diamond - does seem to have been 'a thing'. I've found a few similar examples: [1](https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/638636933/vintage-custom-hand-fabricated-14k), [2](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/wow-unique-antique-mens-mermaid-50ct-1850824422), [3](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1920s-Antique-Art-Nouveau-Deco-14k-Yellow-Gold-Diamond-Chinese-Cocktail-Ring-D8-/283303961300). Nothing to indicate if these have any particular origin/meaning or were just fashionable, though.